# How to set Default Message when there is no data to highcharts in android

Tags: android, highcharts

How to set Default Message(No data to display) when there is no data or user disables the existing chart to highcharts in android

Comment: Hello! Can you please describe the issue you are facing? We can't help until unless you share what you have tried.

Comment: You need to set the visibility on chart to View.GONE and display some message in the separate textView.